# problem in Dictionaries and replace method (python)

Tags: python, function, dictionary, tkinter, replace

im try to make a app witch take words and its trun to security form

its ok with first part
but in second part: i want to turn that word who truned into a security form trun it into a word again and its return incorrect like this :
word: 'hnnh'
sec form: 'yhhy'
But when I try to turn it back, it writes the wrong word: 'nnnn'

and its the problem

code:

```
from tkinter import Tk,Button,Label,Entry



words ={'q':'0','w':'1','e':'2','r':'3','t':'4','y':'5','u':'%','i':'7','o':'8',
    'p':'9','a':'q','s':'w','d':'e','f':'r','g':'t','h':'y','j':'u','k':'i',
    'z':'a','x':'s','c':'d','v':'f','b':'g','n':'h','m':'j','l':'o',
    '1':'z','2':'x','3':'c','4':'v','5':'b','6':'m','7':'.','8':'#','9':'@','0':'!',
    '@':'$','#':':','!':'&',':':'*','.':'n',' ':'6'}


sec ={'0':'q','1':'w','2':'e','3':'r','4':'t','5':'y','%':'u','7':'i','8':'o',
    '9':'p','q':'a','w':'s','e':'d','r':'f','t':'g','y':'h','u':'j',
    'o':'l','a':'z','s':'x','d':'c','f':'v','g':'b','j':'m',
    'z':'1','x':'2','c':'3','v':'4','b':'5','m':'6','.':'7','#':'8','@':'9','!':'0',
    '$':'@',':':'#','&':'!','*':':','6':' ','n':'.','h':'n','i':'k'}
def word_to_sec():
    in_use_words = str(word_to_sec_ent.get())
    for char in words:
        if char in str(word_to_sec_ent.get()):
            in_use_words = in_use_words.replace(char,words[char])
    output = in_use_words  
    config_lbl.config(text= 'word to sec: {}'.format(output))
    return output

def sec_to_word():
    in_use_words = str(sec_to_word_ent.get())
    for chars in words:
        for char in words[chars]:
            if char in str(sec_to_word_ent.get()):
                in_use_words = in_use_words.replace(words[char],char)
    output = in_use_words  
    config_lbl.config(text= 'sec to word: {}'.format(output))
    return output


window = Tk()
window.title('sec_maker           made by: parsa')

word_to_sec_lbl = Label(window,text= 'enter word to convert into the sec form:          ')
word_to_sec_lbl.grid(row=1,column=1)
word_to_sec_ent = Entry(window)
word_to_sec_ent.grid(row=2,column=1)
word_to_sec_btn = Button(window,text='convert to sec form',command=word_to_sec)
word_to_sec_btn.grid(row=3,column=1)

sec_to_word_lbl = Label(window,text= 'enter sec form to convert into the word:')
sec_to_word_lbl.grid(row=1,column=3)
sec_to_word_ent = Entry(window)
sec_to_word_ent.grid(row=2,column=3)
sec_to_word_btn = Button(window,text='convert to word',command=sec_to_word)
sec_to_word_btn.grid(row=3,column=3)

config_lbl = Label(window,text='out put: ')
config_lbl.grid(row=4,column=2)





window.mainloop()
```

Comment: With calling "replace" multiple times you may replace characters which were replacements already. Replace the characters one by one (applies to encryption and decryption).

Comment: yeah i know how can i fix it?

Comment: Iterate over characters (as you do already), for each character find the correct replacement and append replacement character to a result string.

Comment: How can I separate the characters?

Comment: You already iterate over each character in your code.